# RHEL 8.7 Server Unable to "su root" Consistently

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo, redhat-enterprise-linux, su

This particular server was set up with the "[French National Agency for the Security of Information Systems (ANSSI) BP-028 Enhanced Level](https://static.open-scap.org/ssg-guides/ssg-rhel8-guide-anssi_bp28_enhanced.html)" security profile that is packaged with RHEL. After SSHing into my user account, I would like to be able to perform "su root", however this only works sometimes (~1/10 chance). When it does not work, it simply prints "su: Authentication failure".

The following are some important notes:

- The correct password is being input.
- I did search around, I cannot seem to find anyone else who has mentioned this issue.
- If "su root" fails once, it seemingly will not work for that entire SSH session.
- I am using the Google Authenticator PAM module, in case that is relevant.
- "sudo setenforce 0" does not make any difference (thus this likely isn't an selinux issue(?)).
- "sudo -i" and similar do not work due to the security profile (results in "Permission denied" when attempting to access anything).
- Even after performing "sudo passwd root" and successfully changing the password, the issue persists (performing this on other user accounts seems to work though).

Any insight or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is your user in the sudo group?

Comment: @Ramhound Yep, I added an entry for this account within /etc/sudoers with "ALL=(ALL) ALL" which works as expected.